# How to set the url without "site" parameter in google search appliance?

Tags: google-search-appliance

```
 <a class="dn-link" style=" color: #fff;"
    href="{$gsa_search_root_path_prefix}?{$all_results_url}">All results</a>
```

From the above url i want to remove the Site parameter  because i want to pass my own collection as a site parameter,like below

```
<a class="dn-link" style=" color: #fff;"
    href="{$gsa_search_root_path_prefix}?{$all_results_url}&amp;site=erp_collection ">  results</a>
```

Hope some one will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That variable is made from:

```
<xsl:variable name="all_results_url"><xsl:value-of
          select="$no_q_dnavs_params"/>&amp;q=<xsl:value-of select="$original_q"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Which is made from:

```
<!-- *** url without q and dnavs param *** -->
<xsl:variable name="no_q_dnavs_params">
  <xsl:for-each
      select="/GSP/PARAM[(@name != 'start') and
                         (@name != $embedded_mode_root_path_param) and
                         (@name != $embedded_mode_resource_root_path_param) and
                         (@name != $embedded_mode_disable_style) and
                         (@name != 'swrnum') and
                         (@name != 'q') and
                         (@name != 'dnavs') and
                         (@name != 'epoch' or $is_test_search != '') and
                         not(starts-with(@name, 'metabased_'))]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@name = 'ip' and $show_ips_in_search_url = '0'">
        <!-- do nothing to remove 'ip' from the URL -->
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@original_value"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

So you could make your variable up without the site parameter by:

```
 <xsl:variable name="no_q_dnavs_params">
      <xsl:for-each
          select="/GSP/PARAM[(@name != 'start') and
                             (@name != $embedded_mode_root_path_param) and
                             (@name != $embedded_mode_resource_root_path_param) and
                             (@name != $embedded_mode_disable_style) and
                             (@name != 'swrnum') and
                             (@name != 'site') and
                             (@name != 'epoch' or $is_test_search != '') and
                             not(starts-with(@name, 'metabased_'))]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@name = 'ip' and $show_ips_in_search_url = '0'">
            <!-- do nothing to remove 'ip' from the URL -->
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@original_value"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
```

However, i think you want start, dnavs and query in there.  Either way, simply change the != to exclude that parameter from your variable.

Comment: Wow it works. :) You saved my time. Thank you Michael.  Also just want to confirm, removing the site parameter will it affect any other place?

Comment: Feel free to vote up the answer.  You're adding the parameter back so you should be good.  Removing the site parameter will mean the GSA will use the default_collection

Comment: Hi Michael, i want to display the results from off board database connector . Traversal query "select id,post_title,guid,post_content from wp_posts"